# "login failed for user" when connecting to database through javascript

Tags: javascript, sql-server, connection-string

My web page has some links and radio buttons. Selecting a particular link and radio button combination, and then clicking on "Get Results" button would run the query.
But I am getting the below error:
Login failed for user 'dev\rahulsingh'

Below is a sample code:

```
runThisQuery = "select * from DataType_tbl sample (nolock) where sample.dataValue = 'POPULATION';";

var connection = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Connection");
var connectionstring="Data Source=prmserv;Initial Catalog=dataDB;User ID=DOMAIN\\REDACTED;Password=REDACTED;Provider=SQLOLEDB";
connection.Open(connectionstring);
var rs = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Recordset");
rs.Open(runThisQuery, connection);
alert(rs);
```

at the line that says "connection.Open(connectionstring);", I hit an error:

> Login failed for user 'dev\rahulsingh'

I cannot use PHP because I don't know PHP; and I have to do something around this tool, within this month itself.

Please help.

:(

Comment: The error is quite clear: the login failed! Check that you can connect to that database using SSMS with the username and password in your connection string first, before blaming JS.

Comment: did not include sensitive information in client side , use any server side scripting languages .

Comment: If you need to use integrated security you have to specify it and not use user and password in connection string.

Comment: @gvee: the thing is that even if I try using someone else's credentials I am still hitting the login failed error
are you sure there isn't anything wrong with the code, and that the access problem is the only problem here?

Comment: @Arunaprasanth: I won't be hosting this web page anywhere, so this would avoid the security risk. Its just a plain simple page on my system only.

Comment: @user_0: what would be the syntax for that? I'll also try and look google in the mean time

Comment: @Rahul, just take a look here: http://www.connectionstrings.com/  chose your db version, your language and you can find any syntax and variation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have a malformed connection string!

http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/

You are using a windows account (DOMAIN\USERNAME), **not** an SQL login (LOGINNAME).

By specifying a username and password in your connection string, it is assuming you are using SQL Authentication.

Try this instead:

```
Data Source=prmserv;Initial Catalog=dataDB;Provider=SQLOLEDB;Trusted_Connection=True;
```

Comment: Thanks for this info. I didn't know this before. But now that I replaced username and password with Trusted_Connection=True, I am getting the error  

    "  SCRIPT3661: Invalid authorization specification  "  

please help!  

P.S: I opened SSMS and ran the same query manually and it ran correctly.

Comment: @Rahul when you connected in SSMS did you use SQL Auth or Windows Authentication?

Answer (score 0):

@Gvee: Hi the connection string problem is solved. I am using windows authentication. I changed the part 
"Trusted_Connection=True" to 
"Integrated Security=SSPI;"

and its working now. 
But I am now facing problem with getting the recordset output in the alert box. **This is now an entirely different problem I suppose**. The code

```
rs.Open(runThisQuery, connection);
```

runs correctly but the code

```
alert(rs);
```

does not run and I am getting the error

> "String is undefined".

I will try and figure out the reason for this. But If you have to add anything to solve that problem too, I would be more than Grateful.